# Mule Service Proxy, COULD_NOT_READ_XML_STREAM

Tags: soapui, mule

I have a service proxy set up and I am able to view the wsdl, but when I try to test it using soapUI it almost seems to timeout.  I'll post the mule config, and both the soapUI log, and mule studio log.  When I hit the wdsl normally without a proxy, it is a quick response.

Google results don't seem to produce much, so any guidance on the source, soapUI or Mule, and the issue would be helpful.

Mule Flow

```
<flow name="UPCFlow1" doc:name="UPCFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="4040" path="upc" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="text/xml" mimeType="text/xml"/>

    <cxf:proxy-service namespace="http://searchupc.com/" service="UPCSearch" payload="envelope" wsdlLocation="http://www.searchupc.com/service/UPCSearch.asmx?WSDL"  doc:name="SOAP" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false"/>
<http:outbound-endpoint address="http://www.searchupc.com/"
    exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="text/xml" mimeType="text/xml"/>
</flow>
```

soapUI error log

```
    Fri Oct 12 13:32:08 CDT 2012:ERROR:java.net.SocketException: socket closed
   java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:264)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer.readLine(LoggingSessionInputBuffer.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:246)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:204)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:196)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toByteArray(EntityUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity.<init>(BufferedHttpEntity.java:60)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpMethodSupport.getResponseBody(HttpMethodSupport.java:281)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.support.methods.ExtendedPostMethod.getResponseBody(ExtendedPostMethod.java:128)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.SinglePartHttpResponse.<init>(SinglePartHttpResponse.java:49)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.support.attachments.WsdlSinglePartHttpResponse.<init>(WsdlSinglePartHttpResponse.java:36)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.HttpPackagingResponseFilter.wsdlRequest(HttpPackagingResponseFilter.java:71)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.HttpPackagingResponseFilter.afterAbstractHttpResponse(HttpPackagingResponseFilter.java:48)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.afterRequest(AbstractRequestFilter.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:297)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Eclipse Console

```
    INFO  2012-10-12 13:31:06,229 [[upc].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2012-10-12 13:31:06,234 [[upc].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse
INFO  2012-10-12 13:31:06,234 [[upc].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2012-10-12 13:31:06,235 [[upc].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.2040380475'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2012-10-12 13:31:06,239 [[upc].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.2040380475'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
WARN  2012-10-12 13:33:05,590 [[upc].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://searchupc.com/}UPCSearch has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: COULD_NOT_READ_XML_STREAM
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.stax.StaxDataBinding$XMLStreamDataWriter.write(StaxDataBinding.java:133)
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.stax.StaxDataBinding$XMLStreamDataWriter.write(StaxDataBinding.java:117)
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.stax.StaxDataBinding$XMLStreamDataWriter.write(StaxDataBinding.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.resume(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:232)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor$1.write(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:373)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.writeResponse(HttpServerConnection.java:315)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:164)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Duplicate attribute 'name'.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [29,468]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:612)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:485)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:470)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.AttributeCollector.throwDupAttr(AttributeCollector.java:522)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.NsAttributeCollector.resolveNamespaces(NsAttributeCollector.java:248)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.NsInputElementStack.resolveAndValidateElement(NsInputElementStack.java:351)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2923)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2783)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1048)
    at org.mule.module.xml.stax.DelegateXMLStreamReader.next(DelegateXMLStreamReader.java:237)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:551)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:513)
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.stax.StaxDataBinding$XMLStreamDataWriter.write(StaxDataBinding.java:124)
    ... 13 more
ERROR 2012-10-12 13:33:05,595 [[upc].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedOutputStream.writeClosingChunk(ChunkedOutputStream.java:130)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedOutputStream.finish(ChunkedOutputStream.java:144)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.writeResponse(HttpServerConnection.java:319)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:164)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ERROR 2012-10-12 13:33:05,602 [[upc].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.transport.http.ResponseWriter.flush(ResponseWriter.java:69)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.writeResponse(HttpServerConnection.java:300)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:201)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: May I ask why you're not using a `ws-proxy` pattern?

Comment: Yes you may ask, in the end I'd like to use this upc service along side a google ISBN restful service, routing between the two depending on input.  So I'll need a flow not pattern if I understand mule correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were several issues:

- Wrong address of the remote web service,
- Missing `cxf:proxy-client` element,
- Lack of copying SOAPAction over (if not using SOAP 1.2).

Below is the fixed example for SOAP 1.1. Note that I have placed the CXF elements inside the endpoints: this is not a requirement (they could be directly in the flow), but just the usual way of placing them in the configuration.

```
<flow name="UPCFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="4040" path="upc">
        <cxf:proxy-service namespace="http://searchupc.com/"
            service="UPCSearch" payload="body"
            wsdlLocation="http://www.searchupc.com/service/UPCSearch.asmx?WSDL"
            enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <copy-properties propertyName="SOAPAction" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint
        address="http://www.searchupc.com/supc/service/UPCSearch.asmx"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST">
        <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" />
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

And for SOAP 1.2:

```
<flow name="UPCFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="4040" path="upc">
        <cxf:proxy-service namespace="http://searchupc.com/"
            service="UPCSearch" payload="body"
            wsdlLocation="http://www.searchupc.com/service/UPCSearch.asmx?WSDL"
            enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <http:outbound-endpoint
        address="http://www.searchupc.com/supc/service/UPCSearch.asmx"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST">
        <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" soapVersion="1.2" />
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response David.  

-Wrong location of cxf:proxy-service  

I get "Element: Proxy-Service cannot be a child of element HTTP"  
-Missing cxf:proxy-client element  
My understand is you only needed service, and why is this a child of the endpoint?   
-Lack of copying SOAPAction over (if not using SOAP 1.2).  
SOAPAction isn't copied over? is this for mule specifically, and also says soapVersion isn't a valid property

Comment: I've tested both configuration with Mule 3.3.1 and they both work fine. Is "Element: Proxy-Service cannot be a child of element HTTP" a XML editor error or a Mule error? You need a pair of proxy-service and proxy-client if you want your flow to act as a proxy (ie forward remotely). Placing the elements in endpoint is the CXF canonical way of doing things. You need to copy SOAPAction from the inbound properties to the outbound ones. Who says soapVersion not valid? If the XML editor: ignore and run Mule anyways.

Comment: So did you try any of the two configurations?

Comment: Edit: Thanks for the explaination, I need to refresh more.
Both your samples work, but the studio says "Element: Proxy-Service is not allowed to be child of element HTTP" and proxy-client. Also "soapVersion is not defined as a valid property of proxy-client". These aren't available through the GUI, just xml configuration and are flagged. You can be marked correct, but I don't understand the configuration. Care to explain why cxf are where they are.
Thanks

Comment: Just disregard Studio warnings: Studio doesn't support the full extent of Mule XML configuration. For the location of CXF elements: my wording was inaccurate, you can actually have them outside the endpoints, in the flow. The thing is: their standard/canonical location is within endpoints.

Comment: That is very informative thanks for your time David.  I'm surprised the Studio tooling doesn't support all Mule XML configuration. I'm glad to see the configuration can be done through the tooling in the GUI, but the standard (which is defined where?) requires manual xml configuration which is geared more towards power users.